# Laravel get just data from pagination

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

I query the list of users as below:

```php
$users = \App\User::selectRaw('id, "user_name"')->paginate(2);
```

which returns:

```json
{
    current_page: 1,
    data: [
        {
            id: 2,
            user_name: "user_name"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            user_name: "user_name"
        }
    ],
    first_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/users?page=1",
    from: 1,
    last_page: 2,
    last_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/users?page=2",
    next_page_url: "http://localhost:8000/users?page=2",
    path: "http://localhost:8000/users",
    per_page: 2,
    prev_page_url: null,
    to: 2,
    total: 3
}
```

I need to just store the value of users which stored inside `data:` to a variable, how could I achieve it?

Comment: you mean that you need the first 2 users?

Comment: Yes, I mean everything inside `data:[]` access it separately and store it inside another variable.

Comment: Just do `$test = $users['data']`

Comment: @HafezDivandari I tried but its empty and shows nothing.

Comment: @HafezDivandari, I tried this `$users->data` and it throws error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data`

Comment: do you have to use `paginate`? you may `$users = \App\User::selectRaw('id, "user_name"')->take(2);`

Comment: @HafezDivandari, yes I need to use it and the exact query is not with users, I just simplified my question to reduce the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$users = \App\User::selectRaw('id, "user_name"')->paginate(2);

$data = $users->toArray()['data'];
```

Or alternatively:

```
$data = $users->items();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the items in the data as

```php
$users = \App\User::selectRaw('id, "user_name"')->paginate(2);


//$users is an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`
//So to get the items

$users->items();
```

Answer (score -1):

`$users = \App\User::selectRaw('id, email')->paginate(2);`

`$data = $users->getCollection();`

**Edit:**
For those who don't know how to convert "Collection" to "Array", the following link from the official laravel documentation will be helpful: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-toarray

**PS:**

```
> dd($users->getCollection()->toArray())
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "id" => 105135
    "email" => "__anastasia98@xxx.it"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "id" => 93378
    "email" => "__gt72__@xxx.com"
  ]
]
```

Comment: This returns a collection of `User` objects, not an array of values.